# Replace characters inside a RegEx match

Tags: regex, pcre

I want to match certain lines inside any text and inside that match, I want to replace a certain character as often, as it occurs.
Sample Text:

> Any text and "much" "more" of it. Don't replace quotes here
>   **CatchThis(  no quotes here, "any more text"   ,  "and so on and so forth...")**
>   **catchthat("some other text"   , "or less")**
>   some text in "between"
>   **CatchAnything ( "even more"  , "and more", no quotes there, "wall of text")**
>   more ("text"""") and quotes after...

Now I want to replace every quote inside the round brackets with, lets say, a hash sign.
Desired outcome:

> Any text and "much" "more" of it. Don't replace quotes here
>   **CatchThis(  no quotes here, #any more text#   ,  #and so on and so forth...#)**
>   **catchthat(#some other text#   , #or less#)**
>   some text in "between"
>   **CatchAnything ( #even more#  , #and more#, no quotes there, #wall of text# )**
>   more ("text"""") and quotes after...

Matching the lines is easy. Here's my pattern for that:

```
(?i)Catch(?:This|That|Anything)[ \t]*\(.+\)
```

Unfortunately, I have no idea how to match every quote and replace it...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The common approach to matching all occurrences of some pattern inside 2 *different delimiters* is via using [`\G` anchor](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-anchors.html#G) based regular expression.

```
(?i)(?:\G(?!\A)|Catch(?:This|That|Anything)\s*\()[^()"]*\K"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9QNAW9/1).

**Explanation**:

- `(?i)` - case insensitive modifier
- `(?:` - a non-capturing group matching 2 alternatives

  - `\G(?!\A)` - a place in the string right after the previous successful match (as `\G` also matches the start of the string, the `(?!\A)` is necessary to exclude that possibility)
  - `|` - or
  - `Catch(?:This|That|Anything)` - `Catch` followed with either `This` or `That` or `Anything`
  - `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
  - `\(` - a literal `(` symbol
- `)` -  end of the non-capturing group
- `[^()"]*` - any 0+ chars other than `(`, `)` and `"`
- `\K`  - a match reset operator
- `"` - a double quote.

Comment: Very nice! Just what the doctor ordered. Working perfectly...and big thx for the explanation!

Comment: Just in case you need to match multiple tokens in between *multi*character delimiters, I can advise using a ["tempered greedy token"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37343088/3832970) instead of a negated character class (here, `[^()"]*` is used).

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! I'll look it up, but first, I have to fully understand your pattern ;)

Comment: Please let me know which parts confuse you and I will update the answer.

Comment: Much appreciated, Wiktor! I get the single parts, just the whole pattern has not sunk in (yet). Atm, I don't think, I could come up with such a solution by my self, but give it time ;)

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to replace this inside regex? If your regex finds what you want, you can replace character on found string

Comment: That's, what I'm doing right now: get an array of matches, replace the quotes and inject the modified matches back into the original text. Its pretty elaborate and I though, directly replacing inside the matches is much more elegant and maybe faster...